# How to communicate (route traffic?) across two different subnets

Tags: networking, router, routing, port-forwarding, static-routes

A home networking question. I would like hosts on different networks (subnets?) that use the same internet connection to communicate. Two routers, 192.168.2.x connects to the the internet and 192.168.1.x connects to 192.168.2.x.

Router 1: Belkin F9K1102v1 with stock firmware connected to Cable internet. (192.168.2.1)
Router 2: Linksys (Cisco) e4200v1 with TomatoUSB firmware by shibby. (192.168.1.1)
Router 1 connected to the internet.
8 Port Netgear switch connected to Router 1.
Router 1 LAN port connected to WAN port of Router 2.
Router 2 running a VPN on the different subnet and connecting to the internet via Router 1.
NAS connected to Router 1.
WDTV Live connected to Router 2 (to use VPN and geo-blocking facility)

I want the two networks to communicate with each other so that the WDTV can play content from my NAS.

What do I need to buy/do to get them to work?

I have read and read and read, and tinkered and tinkered and cursed, and have dabbled with routing rules? Port forwarding?  and not had success. But I am only tinkering and fuessing trying to implement what I have read and potentially understood. But no success. Placing all hosts on the same subnet is not viable as I want to run a VPN and non-VPN network. I obviously have no formal training in this area.

The following is my home network setup (again). Sorry if I get this technically wrong in my explanation. 
Internet > Cable Modem > Router 1 - gateway 192.168.2.1, mask 255.255.255.0
Router 1 has a NAS attached.
Router 1 LAN port is connected to the WAN port of Router 2 (gateway of 192.168.1.1, mask of 255.255.255.0)
NAS connected to Router 1.
Router 2 is running a OpenVPN client for the purposes of geo-blocking (pretend to be in the US or UK for netflix and BBC iPlayer viewing purposes).

WDTV Live media player is connected to Router 2, so that I can set the loction of the WDTV to either US or UK and view the netflix apps and BBC iPlayer app respectively.

BUT, what I want is the WDTV on network 2 (Router 2) to be able to pull the local content from the NAS that is connected to network 1 (Router 1).

The reason I have two networks is because I want one to run the VPN, and the other to have non-VPN access to the internet. This has two benefits, in that the non-VPN download speed is significantly better, and also I don't have issues with location dependent searches and content being provided (such as google ads for US airlines and forcing me to US and UK sites when I want Australian sites) when just browsing the internet.

Both networks are running WiFi. Ideally I would like to connect to the VPN network from my laptop, and be able to see my NAS. I would also like my VPN network conected WDTV to be able to see my NAS on the other network.

Any assistance to get the WDTV on network 2 to talk to the NAS on network 1 would be great! (I want to leave the NAS on network 1).

Please keep any suggestions in fairly laymans terms (or examples) for a home network tinkerer. THANKS!

John

Comment: You should be able to access your NAS from the VPN network using the NAS's IP address.  It just wouldn't be discoverable using services like UPnP.

Comment: @heavyd his setup looks a bit complicated and my mind is a bit tired, but when you say he should be able to, why do you think he should be able to. It sounds like he might have multiple local subnets,  do you think he has routers that can route between local subnets?    I once called netgear and asked them and they said they don't even sell routers that route between multiple local subnets, just VLAN devices(though that may be largely equivalent, but their basic range don't even do that). Do you really think his can? Note that his belkin is running stock firmware, not ddwrt/tomato.

Comment: @barlop, he has one NAT router behind another NAT router.  Router #2 should be able to communicate with everything in front of it, which includes the Internet and all of the devices behind Router #1.  There are no special routes needed to achieve this.

Comment: @heavyd good point.. I wonder why he says he can't route between the different subnets..  He should try pinging before saying that. . Do you think he even gains any advantage from this use of double NAT?

Comment: i'm curious if your issues would change if you made it the same subnet, but still with the double NAT

Comment: I have tried both routers within the same subnet, with IP range of R1 being say 192.168.2.2-100 and R2 being 192.168.2.150-200. The VPN doesn't seem to work in that config. It only seems to work when both routers are on different subnets <br>

Comment: I connect to R2 and can't ping R1 (and vice versaO so sorry @heavyd but it's not working.  But I am getting to the internet from R2 via R1.

Comment: Ok so backing up a little... it will not work by default because all traffic destined for an external IP from subnet 2 (on router 2) will be directed over the VPN link. That is why he can not communicate between subnets at all.  To add to this... he can't go from subnet 1 to subnet 2 because the gateway doesn't have a specific route to subnet 2 therefore traffic will go to its default gateway (gateway on the WAN link).

Comment: @JohnGriffiths You communicate between different ranges if they are configured as different subnets.  A mask of 255.255.255.0 would not work in a case like that which is what I assume it is in your case.  Either way... because of the routing for the VPN you won't reach back and forth regardless because a request to an external address will be sent out your VPN route (which will totally change the source/dest IPs until it reaches the other end of the VPN link).

Comment: @Goblinlord - So you are saying it is not possible? This is the setup I have as per this youtube video - he seems to believe it is possible but I may be misunderstanding http://youtu.be/yg-V0gMp7vU?t=2m19s

Comment: It is possible... sorry... looking up stuff for tomato so I can give you good instructions.  What I meant was in the default configuration with just those things working it is not possible because of the VPN routing.

Comment: Thanks for your info so far @Goblonlord, I switched off the VPN and then could ping both routers, and also access my NAS using the IP address. But a work-around in tomato so that I can access the other subnet when the VPN is on would be great.

Comment: @JohnGriffiths excellent.  Actually, the youtube video you linked has pretty much what you need for routing.  That solves the issue of routing.  Now if you want the NAS auto-detectable using SMB then you will need setup some NAT entries.  This is more complicated and just the routing should be suffient.  I will post the iptables command first as an answer for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On R2 (your tomato router) goto Administration -> Scripts in the menu on the left of the admin page.  Add the following line and save.

```
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
/usr/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i vlan1 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/usr/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o vlan1 -j ACCEPT
```

Disconnecting and reconnecting the WAN port on R2 should trigger this script.  Test your routing by pinging from subnet 2 to your NAS while the VPN is up.

Comment: Many thanks @Goblinlord. Can now ping both networks when VPN running. Excellent. Thanks for going to so much trouble to actually review the tomato firmware interface, amazingly kind. A gift from a kind soul for me on our national day (Australia Day).